# append values to a list from a tuple in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a code like this,

```
x=[]
y=[]
z=[]
d={u'a':(1,2,4), u'b':(1, 0, 1), u'c':(8, 3,1)}

for k,v in d.items():
       x.append(v[0])
       y.append(v[1])
       z.append(v[2])

m=column_val(x,y) #Function call
n=column_val(x,z)
```

How can i make these steps simpler instead of creating 3 lists?

Comment: Nope, using *one* loop like that is the most efficient way of doing this, short of using a *different* data structure to begin with.

Comment: so you want to end up with just a single list that contains the values, or three separate lists that each contain a single element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `zip()` on `d.values()`:

```
x, y, z = zip(*d.values())
```

This still creates 3 lists, but is more compact. You want to avoid creating loops for the individual `column_val()` parameters, you'd end up with *4* loops instead.

Demo for your `d` sample:

```
>>> d = {u'a': (1,2,4), u'b': (1, 0, 1), u'c': (8, 3,1)}
>>> x, y, z = zip(*d.values())
>>> x, y, z
((1, 8, 1), (2, 3, 0), (4, 1, 1))
```

Note that the *order* of the values in `x`, `y` and `z` is not a given, because dictionaries do not preserve order.